# .conf changes have no effect on reboot in WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've tried making some changes in various .conf files in my Ubuntu WSL2 install, such as editing `/etc/sysctl.conf` with nano, adding `vm.max_map_count=262144` at the end of it, saving, then rebooting Windows, and finally checking if `vm.max_map_count` still `= 262144` ...

When I do a `sysctl vm.max_map_count` it still ends up showing the default `65530`.

However, if I do a `cat /etc/sysctl.conf` I'm still seeing that new line that I added to it, with `262144`?

Comment: Solution posted there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66479410/vm-max-map-count-problem-for-docker-at-windows