# vm.max_map_count problem for docker at windows

Tags: windows, docker

I am trying to run ELK docker images on my windows10 as below.

```
  C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker run  -p 5601:5601 -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -p 5044:5044  -p 9600:9600 -p 9700:9700 -it --memory="3g" --name elk sebp/elk
```

I got below error, could i set vm.max_map_count at  docker run command line?

```
[1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

Any suggestion or hints are more than welcome!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Docker-Desktop for Windows, how can sysctl parameters be configured to permeate a reboot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69214301/using-docker-desktop-for-windows-how-can-sysctl-parameters-be-configured-to-per)

Answer (score 10):

This can be done via WSL's support of a .wslconfig file (stored in your Windows %userprofile% folder), which can apply and persist such setting across restarts, for example:

```
[wsl2]
kernelCommandLine = sysctl.vm.max_map_count=262144
```

(Note that's NOT a space after sysctl, but a period, which is necessary for it to work, from my testing.)

After saving the file, restart wsl with `wsl --shutdown`. Before reopening your WSL, make sure the vm is shutdown, using `wsl -l -v`, as it can take several seconds sometimes.

For more on this file, its many available settings, and even that need to wait for the shutdown, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config).

Comment: This is the best answer! The other solutions require remembering your WSL su password, which I never use.

Answer (score 4):

I've had similar experience with running elastic/elastic, so this might help.

When you're running it in WSL2, you might want to log in to your WSL VM:
`wsl -d docker-desktop` (Where docker-desktop is the name of the vm, you can check for them with `wsl --list`

Once in your docker-desktop, do the following:

`echo "vm.max_map_count = 262144"> /etc/sysctl.d/999-docker-desktop-conf`

followed by:
`sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144`

You can then exit the docker-host by typing `exit`.

Answer (score 0):

Persistent setting via windows powershell:

```
wsl su-
 [sudo] password for root:<type your root password>

sysctl vm.max_map_count
vi /etc/sysctl.conf
  vm.max_map_count = 262144
sysctl -p
sysctl vm.max_map_count
```